# Set cloud_RoleName in app insight from Angular

Tags: angular, azure, azure-application-insights

In services of asp.net we can set cloud_rolename for app insight. Using this our services team tracks error in app insight.
How can i set it from angular. This is how i am running app insight in angular:

```
export class MonitoringService {
private appInsights: ApplicationInsights;
 constructor(private router: Router) {
  this.appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({
   config: {
     instrumentationKey: environment.appInsights.instrumentationKey,
  },
});
this.appInsights.loadAppInsights();
this.loadCustomTelemetryProperties();
this.createRouterSubscription();
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Telemetry Initializers](https://github.com/microsoft/applicationinsights-js#telemetry-initializers), the sample code:

```
var telemetryInitializer = (envelope) => {
  envelope.tags["ai.cloud.role"] = "your role name";
  envelope.tags["ai.cloud.roleInstance"] = "your role instance";
}
appInsights.addTelemetryInitializer(telemetryInitializer);
```

Comment: I get Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts

Comment: This `telemetryInitializer` has to go after the `loadAppInsights()` call, then the error goes away @Enrico